# Deny users to access a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have this upload file structure link localhost:58707/uploads/interaction/5/Chrysanthemum.jpg

I want to deny all the users to access '~/uploads' directly..

So, I put this in my web.config as I see in others questions here:

```
  <location path="~/uploads"> //I've tried '/upload' and 'upload' too.
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest saving the uploaded files to a folder outside of your site root. Then you don't need to worry about it being browsable since it isn't even in the site directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer ..

[Deny access to 'admin' folder in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824494/deny-access-to-admin-folder-in-web-config)

Also

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/how-to-restrict-the-access-to-a-given-folder-for-a-specific-role.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working for my project:
[Use App_Data](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/122/Simple-File-Download-Protection-with-ASP.NET)