# Deny access to 'Upload' folder in web.config for all users in Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I want to dis-allow access to Upload folder, where the files from authorised users are being stored. I want to restrict http://domain.com/Upload/filename.ext.
I have tried `location` tag in root `web.config` as

```
<location path="Upload">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" /> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But still the URL: http://domain.com/Upload/filename.ext is accessible. 
I have also tried adding web.config to Upload folder as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But still no use. Also I have followed some existing posts on Stack Overflow:
[Deny users to access a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694964/deny-users-to-access-a-folder)
[How to restrict folder access in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776847/how-to-restrict-folder-access-in-asp-net)
[Deny access to 'admin' folder in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824494/deny-access-to-admin-folder-in-web-config)
& more but nothing is working for me.
I am using authentication-

```
<authentication mode="None" >
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="15" requireSSL="false" domain=".domain.com"/>
    </authentication>
```

Need help on this security issue...

Comment: Are you using IIS as a web server?

Comment: @teovankot yes, I am using IIS8 on windows server 2012 R2